# Google Sheets highlight lowest number in each row script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to highlight the lowest number in every second row. All the odd numbers starting from row 2. I can loop the rows but I cannot get the min cell.

Data:

```
Gate1    Gate2    Gate3    Gate4
  12      45        7        8
Gate1    Gate2    Gate3    Gate4
  5      57        4        10
Gate1    Gate2    Gate3    Gate4
  12      45        7        8
```

The script so far

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var startRow = 2;


  for ( var i = startRow; i <= mySheet.getLastRow(); i++){
    //Get the lowest value in the row and change cells text color to green

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to change the background color of cells to green color.
- You want to change the color when the value of cell is the minimum number in each row.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve all values using `getDataRange()` and `getValues()`.
2. For rows of odd number, retrieve the minimum number for each row. And set the color. In this case, it's `green`.
3. The colors are set using `setBackgrounds()`.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var colLen = values[0].length;
  var colors = values.map(function(row, i) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      var min = Math.min.apply(null, row);
      return row.map(function(col) {return col == min ? "green" : null});
    }
    return new Array(colLen);
  });
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this script, `null` is used as the color except for the minumum value. But if you want to give the color for it, please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
          return row.map(function(col) {return col == min ? "green" : null});
        }
        return new Array(colLen);
    ```
  - To

    ```
          return row.map(function(col) {return col == min ? "green" : "white"});
        }
        return Array.apply(null, new Array(colLen)).map(function(_, i) {return "white"});
    ```

#### References:

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getvalues)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setbackgroundscolor)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

From your shared Spreadsheet, above script was modified for it.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var colLen = values[0].length;
  var colors = values.map(function(row, i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      row.shift();
      var min = Math.min.apply(null, row);
      return [null].concat(row.map(function(col) {return col == min ? "green" : null}));
    }
    return new Array(colLen);
  });
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately it has no effect on my spreadsheet. Just to clarify. In my above example data, on row 2 the 7 will be highlighted. Skip row 3 and on row 4 highlight the 4 etc.

Comment: @Keith Power Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I would like to resolve the issue. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Keith Power By the way, for example, when the values of `Gate1,Gate2,Gate3,Gate4` are put to the column "A" to "D" of the row 1 and the values of `12,45,7,8` are put to the column "A" to "D" of the row 2, and those values are put in the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet, the script changes the background color of the cell "C2" which has the value of `7`. By this, I cannot replicate your situation. So I need the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue.

Comment: Here is sample spreadsheet data. Sheet 1 is the data and sheet 2 is an example where I highlighted the lowest value in the row for the first couple https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KUim0cWilKNumhdK2RCb-lf6mD1g1vOnxr_xdM-w-pE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Keith Power Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. I found the reason of your issue. That is due to the different format between the sample values in your question and your shared Spreadsheet. In my script, the numbers that you want to change the background colors are put to the row 2, row 4,,,. And each number is put from the column "A". But in your shared Spreadsheet, this is different. I apologize my script cannot work at various formats. So I modified the sample script for working at your shared Spreadsheet. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Keith Power Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.